# Error while importing into table in SQL Server 2008 R2 from Excel File

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting this error while importing from an Excel file into a table in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have added a picture.

> Copying to [dbo].[MultiPLU] (Error) Messages Error 0xc0202009: Data
>   Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has
>   occurred.
>   Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"
>   Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
>
> An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"
>   Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PLUCode', table 'AR4UWin.dbo.MultiPLU'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "input "Destination Input"
>   (57)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row
>   disposition on "input "Destination Input" (57)" specifies failure on
>   error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component. There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component
>   "Destination - MultiPLU" (44) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while
>   processing input "Destination Input" (57). The identified component
>   returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific
>   to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow
>   task to stop running. There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.

(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 0):

The import process requires a value for every row in the 'PLUCode' column, whereas I believe that your excel spreadsheet sometimes has no value in these cells.

Comment: ""Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PLUCode'" from your error message suggests otherwise

Comment: would u by any chance have team viewer?

Comment: not where I am, no. I would advise that you first check the values in your spreadsheet, and then check that the column is correctly mapped in your import definition

Comment: Thanks Paul. I managed to import the file, there were duplicate fields. However, I now need to convert the table to flat file.

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking on the PLUCode and setting it to allow nulls will allow you to upload the table. The query below will give you the errored entries for review.

```
SELECT *
FROM Tablename
WHERE PLUCode IS NULL
```

If you're dealing with duplicates I would recommend a self join to only give you the unique rows. (You'll need a few 'if' statements to check for rows with null values so you don't delete a whole record and leave you with the broken one.) I would be exceptionally careful with using any predefined remove duplicates function (like in excel) unless you've scrutinized the table to ensure it wont drop the completed rows.

EDIT: To respond the need to save as a flat file you'll want to save as a comma delimited csv file. Its in the usual file formats list unless you're using excel 2010, the itll be under the "Save and Send" option.